# How to dynamically build booleanbuilder condition with many ORs

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need to build a BooleanBuilder condition with many ORs.

I have a method with 2 input parameters:

```
User findUser(String inputname, List<String> inputcities);
```

And there I have a code:

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
builder.and(user.name(inputname));
```

How should I dynamically build it for many cities, as an OR?
To check if user is from one of those cities given in array?
So array might contain 5, 10 cities. How I can make it without harcoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming User entity has a foreign key, referencing a City entity, I suggest you use an sql-query similar to the following:

```
select  u.*
  from  User u
  where u.NAME = :inputname
    and u.CITY_ID in :inputcities
```

The easiest way to implement it is using Spring Data's JPA Repository.
If you do so, you won't need any BooleanBuilder's or another custom stuff.

If something is still unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks! This part is understandable. But I need it in the form of BooleanBuilder and JPA. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @jack, do you need a query in form of many ORs or maybe an IN clause is preferable?

Comment: that's not important. Both cases are fine. Just in form of BooleanBuilder, as it is mentioned in my topic description.

Comment: try using the following code: BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder(user.name.eq(inputname)).and(user.city.in(inputcities));